# How do I replace `\n` in a string but not `\n\n` in Python?

Tags: python, string

I have the following string:

```
mystring = '\n\nAvailability:\n  Open source,  \n\nResource Name:\n  QIIME  \n\nResource ID:\n                        SCR_008249'
```

I wanted to replace **\n** from the above string, but not **\n\n**.

So I tried this:

```
new_string = " ".join(mystring.split())
```

And found this:

`'Availability: Open source, Resource Name: QIIME, Resource ID: SCR_008249'`

But I wanted something like this:

```
'Availability: Open source, 
 Resource Name: QIIME Resource 
 ID: SCR_008249'
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think that answer is over-complicated for this question... one sec

Comment: There are slices for it

Comment: @mkrieger1 No. The result from that answer does not look like what I desire.

Comment: @BekaluTadesse your expected output has replaced \n\n with \n , is that right?

Comment: Shame this was closed. The other answer definitely over-complicates things. A simple `re.sub(r'\n(\n)?', r'\1', mystring)` solves your stated problem. However, the output looks different from your output, because your output does not conform to your requirement.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Maybe add a simpler answer to the other question if appropriate?

Comment: The "something like" looks problematic: QTIME and Resource should not be in the same row according to the logic provided by the OP.

Comment: Sorry, not a duplicate (the other question needs to handle `\r` as well, which makes the query a lot more complex).

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex:

```
import re

print(re.sub(r'\n(\n)?', r'\1', mystring))
```

This solves your stated problem. However, the output looks different from your output, because your output does not conform to your requirement.

If you also want to normalise whitespace, throw in some whitespace-sponging pattern, e.g.

```
print(re.sub(r'\n(\n)? *', r'\1 ', mystring))
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to split it by `\n\n\`, remove the `\n` from each part, then put it back together again:

```
mystring = '\n\nAvailability:\n  Open source,  \n\nResource Name:\n  QIIME  \n\nResource ID:\n                        SCR_008249'

new_string = "\n\n".join([x.replace("\n","") for x in mystring.split("\n\n")])

print(repr(new_string))
```

output:

`'\n\nAvailability:  Open source,  \n\nResource Name:  QIIME  \n\nResource ID:                        SCR_008249'`

Comment: this doesn't give the desired output

Comment: @coderoftheday it gives "something like" the desired output which is what OP asked! The desired output in the question obviously has been modified in other ways than the specific question, e..g removing whitespace on the last line, which this doesn't do because that wasn't the question.

Comment: but the op wanted ```QIIME Resource ``` not ```Resource ID on one line```

Comment: @coderoftheday they may well have done but that requires a separate operation outside the scope of this question, there is a \n\n between QIME and Resource which they want to retain...

Comment: @JeffUK Thanks, it works but one more problem. There is an undesired space between Resource ID and SCR_008249 : 

`Availability:  Open source,  


Resource Name:  QIIME  


Resource ID:                        SCR_008249`

Comment: @BekaluTadesse this code will neither remove nor add spaces, those spaces are in your input string.